# How can I get this PHP variable to be determined by the value of another user selected radio button

Tags: php, string, conditional-statements

```
$door = $_POST["doorType"];  

$doorWidth;
if ($door=="Single")
{
        $doorWidth = $width;
}
else if ($door=="Double")
{
$doorWidth = $dOneWidth;
}
```

When I run the page it doesn't recognize the variable $doorWidth?

Comment: spare $doorWidth what are @width and $dOneWidth

Comment: maybe $_POST['doorType'] is empty.

Answer (score 1):

```
$doorWidth;
```

doesn't assign anything. It only returns the variable ... to anything. Doing this PHP is accessing the variable, causing a notice. Write for example:

```
$doorWidth = NULL; // assigns something (some default value if $door isn't "Signle" nor "Double")
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess that `$door` has a value far from `Single|Double`. This may be caused by another error in your application. You should learn, that you should *in any case* set a proper default value for a variable if you are about to assign to it from into a conditional statement (like `if`):

```
$doorWidth = 'not set!';

if ($door=="Single")
{
    $doorWidth = $width;
}
else if ($door=="Double")
{
    $doorWidth = $dOneWidth;
}
```

Further note about the [`switch`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) statement which has a `default:` branch:

```
switch($door) {
    case 'Single' : 
        // do something
        break;
    case 'Double' :
        // do something else
        break;
    default:
        die('$door has a value far from 'Single|Double'. Currently: ' . $door);
}
```

Comment: The problem is that I know door is = to Single because if I echo $door i get Single?

Comment: when I run it and I try to Echo $doorWidth I am just getting a blank?